# A function works when I use gcc, but when I use Microsoft Visual Studio's compiler it does nothing

Tags: c, handle, createfile

When I run this with `gcc` using code:blocks, it creates the **registration.txt** on F if it doesn't exist and writes the password and username, but when I use this in my project using Microsoft Visual Studio's compiler it does nothing.

For example if I call this function such as: `Write("JohnDoe", "password123")`, 
in the file **registration.txt** should appear in a line: `JohnDoe, password123`.

```
const char *FILEPATH = "F:\\registration.txt";

int Write(char *username, char *password) {
    if (username == NULL || password == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    BOOL error = TRUE;
    size_t lengthUsername = strlen(username);
    size_t lengthPassword = strlen(password);
    LPDWORD bytesUsernameWritten = 0;
    char comma[2] = ",";
    char newLine[3] = "\r\n";
    LPDWORD bytesPasswordWritten = 0;
    LPDWORD bytesWrittenComma = 0;
    //if the file doesn't exist, we create it
    HANDLE file = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)FILEPATH, FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_FILE_EXISTS) {
            printf("0x%x", GetLastError());
            CloseHandle(file);
            return -1;
        }  //the file exist, we try to create it
        file = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)FILEPATH, FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            printf("Couldn't open the file. Error : 0x%x", GetLastError());
            CloseHandle(file);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    //We try to write the username and the password in file, each combination on each line, in this format: username, password

    error = WriteFile(file, username, (DWORD)lengthUsername, bytesUsernameWritten, NULL);
    if (error == FALSE) {
        printf("The username couldn't have been written. Error 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(file);
        return -1;
    }
    error = WriteFile(file, comma, 1, bytesWrittenComma, NULL);
    if (error == FALSE) {
        printf("The comma couldn't have been written. Error 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(file);
        return -1;
    }
    error = WriteFile(file, password, (DWORD)lengthPassword, bytesPasswordWritten, NULL);
    if (error == FALSE) {
        printf("The password couldn't have been written. Error 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(file);
        return -1;
    }
    error = WriteFile(file, newLine, 2, bytesPasswordWritten, NULL);
    if (error == FALSE) {
        printf("The endline couldn't have been written. Error 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(file);

        return -1;
    }
    CloseHandle(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When the function doesn't create the file, what error message does it print? If nothing, you may try single-stepping through the lines in a debugger, or add more printf()s to see which branches it is executing.

Comment: Add a break point at the first line of  ```int Write(char* username, char* password)``` 
 by type ```F9```, then start to debug by ```F5```. If it stopped at the break point, click ```F10``` to debug it step by step to get reason why it running to failed.

Comment: VS told you that you were doing it wrong but shot the messenger by adding the (LPCWSTR) casts.  Required reading [is here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 4):

Your main problem is confusion between using Unicode and ASCII.

All windows API functions that take string parameters have two versions:
One that works with `LPCSTR` and one that works with `LPCWSTR`.

You can cast `char *` to `LPCSTR` and use the ASCII version `CreateFileA`, but you can not cast it to `LPCWSTR` and use the `CreateFileW` - the Unicode version of `CreateFile` as it expects strings in UCS-16 encoding where each character takes 2 bytes.

Which version of the function is called depends on a compiler flag. For CodeBlocks on Windows the default is to use ASCII versions, so your function works.
For VS the default is Unicode, so the file path string gets messed up and the file is not created.

Also, you have two other erros:

1. You are using `WriteFile` incorrectly. 
   The 4th parameter is a pointer, where `WriteFile` stores number of bytes written.

   You are passing a NULL pointer, because you set variables such as `bytesUsernameWritten` to 0. But according to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile), you can only use NULL there if the last parameter, `lpOverlapped` is not NULL.

   What you should do, is declare `bytesUsernameWritten` to be DWORD and pass its address using `&` operator.
   Otherwise, even if the function creates the file successfully, you will not get the number of bytes that were written.
2. You are trying to close `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`
   This is unnecessary, but fortunately it should not crash you program.

Finally, there is no reason to try to call `CreateFile` twice.
Just use one call with `OPEN_ALWAYS` parameter.
This will open an existing file, but if the file does not exist it will create it automatically instead of failing.